# How to prevent normal map baking cage from self-intersecting?

Tags: baking, displacement

I need to use a cage for baking a normal map for a retopo mesh from a sculpted mesh. The typical solutions I see for creating the cage in this situation are to create a copy of the low-poly mesh and scale it out along the normals, or to use a displace modifier to the same effect.

However, I'm observing that using the displace modifier leads to issues and artifacts where the cage is self-intersecting, particularly in areas like between the toes or around the mouth/ears where there are crevices. I don't want the cage to go through itself in these areas, but I need to scale it out far enough that it will fully surround the high poly surface everywhere else.

Is there a good solution to prevent self-intersecting when using the displace modifier that is not a highly manual process?